# die vs echo php error message giving me problems

Tags: php

am using recaptcha. orignally the error was used using 'die' but this took my to another page and gave me an error.

because i want it to show in the page, i used print.

The problem with echo is the function doesnt work:

this is my site :

http://www.the-big-bbq.co.uk/invitation.php#prettyPhoto

my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "6LeBwPcSAAAAAL2pNriaDSi8ca0Yb1qewzfDMYyY";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
// What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
echo $myDiv1;   

} else {
// Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
}
?>
```

This is the html

```
        <p class="myDiv1">Please enter the text shown</p>
```

originally it was using this:

```
     die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
```

how can i use echo, but show it only when they have entered wrong details.

Comment: Don't use `die`. That is almost the worst way to handle an error. Navigate back  for the user, inform the user of the error, and propose a solution if the call to action is not intuitive.

Comment: i tried using echo instead but it doesnt work

Comment: I've absolutely no idea where your problem is. Did you use print or echo? What is the content of $myDiv1. It will be send to the browser if validation fails. If it's empty, nothing will be send.

Comment: the echo prints when browser is opened but if you enter the wrong details it still works, when it shouldnt.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is output what you want in this situation with one or many `echo` statements.

I had no idea what `$myDiv1` was so I just did it manually.

Like so:-

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "6LeBwPcSAAAAAL2pNriaDSi8ca0Yb1qewzfDMYyY";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        echo '<p class="myDiv1">';
        echo "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.";
        echo ' (reCAPTCHA said: ' . $resp->error . ')';
        echo '</p>'; 

    } else {
        // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: no with echo it shows it when i open the browser: http://www.the-big-bbq.co.uk/invitation.php#prettyPhoto

Comment: It only shows if `$resp->is_valid` is false. Maybe you need to check the other code is working properly

Comment: everything id working now, but what i need now is to link the validator to my fourm...

Comment: That will be another question as only one question is allowed per thread. That makes this site into a useful resource for other to learn from. You can ask as many questions as you like, but you have to have a go at doing it yourself first. This is not a free coding service.